# how to translate scraped text using google translator API

Tags: python, language-translation

I scraped a book off Project Gutenberg using beautiful soup in jupyter notebook, and want to translate it into another language. However, had trouble doing so.

Would be grateful for help/advice; my code so far is below.The translation code did not work, and returned the following error "WriteError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe"

```
#Store url

url = 'https://www.gutenberg.org/files/514/514-h/514-h.htm'
html = r.text
print(html)
#Create a BeautifulSoup object from the HTML
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html5lib")
type(soup)

#get rid of non-text 

paragraph=soup.find_all("p")
for para in paragraph:
    print(para.text)

#translate text using google API translator
#init the Google API translator

translator = Translator()
translation = translator.translate(text,dest="ar")
print(translation)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `translator.translate(text,dest="ar")` method does not return a string, rather instead returns an instance.

Try the following snippet:

```
translation = translator.translate(text,dest="ar")
print(translation.text)
```

[For more information.](https://stackabuse.com/text-translation-with-google-translate-api-in-python/)

Comment: thanks very much! this is very helpful. I managed to translate a single para. However, how can I translate the whole text? the text is saved in a for loop (see below). not sure how to convert that to a variable. 

for para in paragraph:
    print(para.text)

Comment: `new_var = ""  
for para in paragraph:  
    new_var += para.text  
print(new_var)`